# wordpress gravity form auto fill/select with current page title

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, conditional-statements, gravity-forms-plugin

I was wondering if it was possible to make a select dropdown inside a gravity form that can auto select a dropdown item according to the current page that it was loaded in.

For example:

I have 2 pages:

page A
page B

On every page I have the same form (form is made once).
And in that form I have a dropdown with 2 items (page A and page B)

But when I load page A I would like to make sure that the dropdown auto selects page A so that i can use conditional logic.

Ditto for page B.

How can i make sure that this will be possible in a short amount of time?

This is what i did so far:

**app.js**

```
 e('.button[href^="#"]').on("click", e.proxy(this.openModal, this)),
                                        this.prefillPopup();
    prefillPopup: function () {
                                    var i = parseInt(e("body").attr("class").split(" ")[2].replace("page-id-", ""));
                                    e("#input_5_8").val(
                                        {
                                            427: "Personeelsfeest",
                                            429: "Bedrijfsfeest",
                                            431: "Walking en seated diners",
                                            433: "Seminaries & Presentaties",
                                            435: "Productlancering",
                                            437: "Modeshows",
                                            439: "Event op maat",
                                            440: "Activiteiten",
                                        }[i]
                                    );
                                },
```

What i did is creating  function that when the popup modal is opened/loaded the dropdown will be automatically filled with the data that I want it to be filled with.

The only thing is that it doesn't fill up with the content that I specify.

The dropdown needs to be filled with the desired titled related to the page ID that is being viewed in the browser at that time.

Comment: _“How can i make sure that this will be possible in a short amount of time?”_ - IMHO, that is not a way in which you should ask here. What have _you_ done so far to try and solve this? That plugin has quite decent documentation for developers.

Comment: I made edits to my question. thanks for mentioning.